# Integrating Push API Persistence

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, push-api

I'm trying to integrate persistent push notification with Push API in a PWA, i saw in the docs that it's possible to do that but i can't see any example or what so ever to do that, is there a tutorial that can help me achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `requireInteraction` flag in order to make a notification persistent (i.e. do not hide it after a few seconds automatically).

Currently this flag is supported only by some browsers.

Here you can find more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification

Comment: @Garsivirus Persistent notifications are not supported yet by Chrome mobile... but that is probably a choice. Maybe you can report your feature request here: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines